# gitignore for folder of eclipse projects

Tags: eclipse, git, multiple-projects

I am working following a set of java swing tutorials, each is an Eclipse project, keep them in a workspace. I init a git repository in the workspace folder (mac), and upload to github. When I download this folder in another computer (linux), the projects are not recognized as such, and opening/importing in Eclipse fails. Says: 'Folder not recognized as project'. What is the best way to handle a collection of projects in git?

Comment: can you post the gitignore, pls?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have all of your Eclipse project data across your machines, you will have to add the following files/folders to Git:

- .classpath
- .project
- .settings (folder)

Make sure that these are not ignored in either your local or globale `.gitignore` files.

Ignore things like the `bin` and `target` folders, since they contain the compiled classes and shouldn't be added to Git.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the failed import: as @nwinkler writes, Eclipse looks for the `.project` and .`classpath` files so you need to add them  (and the `.settings` directory) to your git repository.

Regarding `.gitignore`, I typically put the workspace stuff there (and then do `import existing projects` in eclipse after cloning):

That is,

```
.metadata/.plugins
.metadata/.lock
.metadata/.log
```

and then for each project, the bin folder

```
project_dir/bin
```

and any other generated files