# Files to be included in gitignore list for an Eclipse Project

Tags: java, eclipse, git, gitignore

What files and directories should I add to my `.gitignore` file for a java applet style eclipse project?

Later if I clone these projects on a different computer, I should be able to build an eclipse project with minimal effort.

Below is the directory structure of my project.

```
./.classpath
./.DS_Store
./.project
./build
./build/2.5_week.atom
./build/airports.dat
./build/blankDark-1-3.mbtiles
./build/blankLight-1-3.mbtiles
./build/city-data.json
./build/countries.geo.json
./build/demos
./build/demos/Airport.class
./build/demos/EarthquakeCityMapDemo.class
./build/demos/LifeExpectancy.class
./build/demos/LocationTester.class
./build/demos/MyDisplay.class
./build/demos/MyPApplet.class
./build/demos/Person.class
./build/demos/SearchAndSort.class
./build/demos/SimpleLocation.class
./build/demos/Student.class
./build/HelloUCSDWorld.class
./build/hs_err_pid28422.log
./build/hs_err_pid28889.log
./build/java.policy.applet
./build/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv
./build/LifeExpectancyWorldBankModule3.csv
./build/module1
./build/module1/HelloWorld.class
./build/module3
./build/module3/EarthquakeCityMap.class
./build/module4
./build/module4/CityMarker.class
./build/module4/EarthquakeCityMap.class
./build/module4/EarthquakeMarker.class
./build/module4/LandQuakeMarker.class
./build/module4/OceanQuakeMarker.class
./build/module5
./build/module5/CityMarker.class
./build/module5/CommonMarker.class
./build/module5/EarthquakeCityMap.class
./build/module5/EarthquakeMarker.class
./build/module5/LandQuakeMarker.class
./build/module5/OceanQuakeMarker.class
./build/module6
./build/module6/AirportMap.class
./build/module6/AirportMarker.class
./build/module6/CityMarker.class
./build/module6/CommonMarker.class
./build/module6/EarthquakeCityMap.class
./build/module6/EarthquakeMarker.class
./build/module6/LandQuakeMarker.class
./build/module6/LifeExpectancy.class
./build/module6/OceanQuakeMarker.class
./build/OfflineMapApp.class
./build/palmTrees.jpg
./build/parsing
./build/parsing/ParseFeed.class
./build/quiz1.atom
./build/quiz2.atom
./build/routes.dat
./build/sortAndPrint.test2.out.txt
./build/test1.atom
./build/test1.out.txt
./build/test2.atom
./build/test2.out.txt
./data
./data/2.5_week.atom
./data/airports.dat
./data/blankDark-1-3.mbtiles
./data/blankLight-1-3.mbtiles
./data/city-data.json
./data/countries.geo.json
./data/LifeExpectancyWorldBank.csv
./data/LifeExpectancyWorldBankModule3.csv
./data/palmTrees.jpg
./data/quiz1.atom
./data/quiz2.atom
./data/routes.dat
./data/sortAndPrint.test2.out.txt
./data/test1.atom
./data/test1.out.txt
./data/test2.atom
./data/test2.out.txt
./lib
./lib/core.jar
./lib/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-amd64.jar
./lib/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar
./lib/gluegen-rt-natives-linux-i586.jar
./lib/gluegen-rt-natives-macosx-universal.jar
./lib/gluegen-rt-natives-windows-amd64.jar
./lib/gluegen-rt-natives-windows-i586.jar
./lib/gluegen-rt.jar
./lib/jogl-all-natives-linux-amd64.jar
./lib/jogl-all-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar
./lib/jogl-all-natives-linux-i586.jar
./lib/jogl-all-natives-macosx-universal.jar
./lib/jogl-all-natives-windows-amd64.jar
./lib/jogl-all-natives-windows-i586.jar
./lib/jogl-all.jar
./lib/json4processing.jar
./lib/libTUIO.jar
./lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar
./lib/sqlite-jdbc-3.7.2.jar
./lib/unfolding.0.9.7-uscd.jar
./LICENSE.txt
./README
./src
./src/demos
./src/demos/Airport.java
./src/demos/EarthquakeCityMapDemo.java
./src/demos/LifeExpectancy.java
./src/demos/LocationTester.java
./src/demos/MyDisplay.java
./src/demos/MyPApplet.java
./src/demos/Person.java
./src/demos/SearchAndSort.java
./src/demos/SimpleLocation.java
./src/demos/Student.java
./src/HelloUCSDWorld.java
./src/module1
./src/module1/HelloWorld.java
./src/module3
./src/module3/EarthquakeCityMap.java
./src/module4
./src/module4/CityMarker.java
./src/module4/EarthquakeCityMap.java
./src/module4/EarthquakeMarker.java
./src/module4/LandQuakeMarker.java
./src/module4/OceanQuakeMarker.java
./src/module5
./src/module5/CityMarker.java
./src/module5/CommonMarker.java
./src/module5/EarthquakeCityMap.java
./src/module5/EarthquakeMarker.java
./src/module5/LandQuakeMarker.java
./src/module5/OceanQuakeMarker.java
./src/module6
./src/module6/AirportMap.java
./src/module6/AirportMarker.java
./src/module6/CityMarker.java
./src/module6/CommonMarker.java
./src/module6/EarthquakeCityMap.java
./src/module6/EarthquakeMarker.java
./src/module6/LandQuakeMarker.java
./src/module6/LifeExpectancy.java
./src/module6/OceanQuakeMarker.java
./src/OfflineMapApp.java
./src/parsing
./src/parsing/ParseFeed.java
```

What files can be safely ignored so that I can build these projects later on a different machine? Can I ignore the `.jar` files? I [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116121/should-i-keep-my-project-files-under-version-control/119377#119377) [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30865009/gitignore-for-folder-of-eclipse-projects) it is safe to have my `.classpath` and `.project` in Git. My [current](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16736856/what-should-be-in-my-gitignore-for-an-android-studio-project) `.gitignore` file has these items.

```
.DS_Store
doc/
bin/
gen/
build/

*.html
*.log
*.class
```

Comment: Are you using maven or any other dependency/build management tool?

Comment: Yes I am using maven